# Regex: match the patterns as many times as there are inside a given string

Tags: .net, regex

I have this kind of pattern:

```
OPEN whatevertag="blabla" content="what i need" blabla="blabla" content="some more content i need" CLOSE`
```

I need to get all the values for content (all of them) but they need to be between `OPEN` and `CLOSE`. How could I do that?

I know that I could get all of these with `/content="(.*?)"/` if there was no need to match only what is between OPEN and CLOSE but right now I am stuck.

I need:

```
what i need
some more content i need
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the programming language / regex flavor?

Comment: This looks like a segment of XML..?  In which case an XPath query might be a better choice to obtain the content attribute value?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is coded inside a .Net software, thanks

Comment: @NickAllan the overall structure may vary (more or less elements) so I am not certain XPath could handle that easily?

Comment: I am not sure what you need exactly. The regex as is won't help much, it should be used with specific code. Can you add code, or do you want to just provide a regex that will return matches/groups? BTW, if it is XML, better use XML parser.

Comment: Also, see https://regex101.com/r/3Be6TF/1.